# find nested checkboxlist in repeater control with jquery

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008, nested, element

Using VS 2008, I have a Repeater control with nested elements and want to select one of them (the checkboxes) with jquery.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="storesRep" DataSourceID="storeSqlDataSource" OnItemDataBound="StoresRep_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table style="padding:0px">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:200px"><asp:Label ID="infoLbl" runat="server">Choose stores for upload:</asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="width:110px"><asp:Label ID="storeLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="storeCheck" CssClass="storeCheck" /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <table runat="server" id="footerTbl" visible="false" style="padding:0px">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:200px"><asp:Label ID="infoLbl" runat="server">Choose stores for upload:</asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblEmptyData" Text="No Stores found." runat="server" ForeColor="GrayText"></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>
            </table>        
         </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Here is my script

```
$('#<%= uploadBtn.ClientID %>').click(
    function() {

        //check if store was chosen from list
        var storeChecked = false;
        $('#<%= storeCheck.ClientID %>').each(function() {

            if ($(this).attr('checked'))
                storeChecked = true;
        });
        if (storeChecked == false) {
            alert("Upload is only possible if a store has been chosen from list.");
            return false;
        }
```

I get the compiler error "storeCheck is not a known name in the current context".

Comment: How are you trying to select it?

Comment: "When selecting" ...do you mean "when jquery selector runs on the client-side"? I ask because of the word "compiler" in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you are trying to access storeCheck using it's ID and storeCheck only exists in the context of the repeater.

What you should do is use the class instead. So change:

```
$('#<%= storeCheck.ClientID %>').each(function() {
```

to

```
$('.storeCheckBox').each(function() {
```

You can also change you code to this which just checks if there are any checked checkboxes with the class of storeCheck:

```
$('#<%= uploadBtn.ClientID %>').click(function() {
    if($('span.storeCheck input:checked').length == 0) {
        alert("Upload is only possible if a store has been chosen from list.");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Changed the code as it appears that asp.net puts the checkbox inside a span with the class you supply rather than applying it straight to the checkbox.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/rAVLA/1/

Comment: No, it doesn´t help! The alert fires always, even if I choose a store from the repeater.

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle test that works. Can you check yours against that?

Comment: Updated now to account for the way asp.net handles cssclass attribute on checkboxes. Hopefully it should work now.