# How to get nested control's ClientID using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Today I got an interview question as titled.

For example, a Update Panel contains a Panel, the Panel contains a TextBox.

How can I get the TextBox ClientID?

The only I could think of that is:

1. We can predict the TextBox ClientID depends on the ClientID mode and use getElementByID.

   i.e. `getElementByID('ct100$MasterPageBody$ct100$UpdatePanelID$ct100$PanelID$ct100$TextBoxID')`
2. We can use JavaScript to parse the HTML, parse the input controls into arrays.

   i.e Assume we know we want to find the first UpdatePanel's first Panel's first TextBox.
   We can find it from myUpdatePanel[0] then get its children using JavaScript? (I am only guessing here)
3. `getElementByID('<%=MyTextBox.ClientID%>')`

But assuming the TextBox is added dynamic, but what's the proper way of doing it?

Comment: you may also try this for more use over nested controls:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275693/find-nested-checkboxlist-in-repeater-control-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the control from a jQuery selector based on the end of the id like the example here:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnable" Text="My Checkbox" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var checked = $("input[id$=chkEnable]").attr("checked");

    });
</script>
```

Here's an article for the exact thing:
http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2009/02/09/jquery-get-a-handle-on-a-server-element-in-javascript-without-using-lt-elem-clientid-gt.aspx

Comment: Excellent answer!  Used this to find the id of an asp.net text box on a child control.  The traditional "<%=textBox.ClientID%>" won't work since the ClientID call is on a control where the textbox doesn't exist (i.e. the child control).  This worked perfectly to get around that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this JQUERY

```
$("input[type='text']:first")
```

Example of Set focus on First Textbox

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       // focus on the first text input field in the first field on the page
        $("input[type='text']:first", document.forms[0]).focus();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

`var $textboxes = $("input[type='text']")`

Now, `$textboxes` is an array of jquery objects representing all textboxes on the page, so you can do something like

```
$.each($textboxes, function(index, obj) {
  // do something to check if this is the textbox that you are looking for...
});
```