# How to get full ClientID for a control from server side code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `TextBox` inside `ItemTemplate` of a `Repeater` that is also inside a `ItemTemplate`.

Server side I have:

```
protected void txtValorMaterialAsign_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string controlId = ((TextBox)sender).ClientID;
}
```

which results in:

`rptFilasDeUnMaterial_ctl04_txtValorMaterialAsign`

But client side the Id for that control is (according to Chrome's F12):

```
ctl00_contenido_wucMateriales_rptMateriales_ctl00_rptFilasDeUnMaterial_ctl01_txtValorMaterialAsign
```

How can I get the full Id from server side code?

Comment: What is the name of the TextBox in your asp.net Application..? then I can show you a simple way of getting it..

Comment: that textbox is inside the reapeter (rtpMateriales) and that is inside a contentPlaceholder (contenido).

Comment: @DJKRAZE it is called txtValorMaterialAsign

Comment: You will have to use FindControl() and cast it to your TextBox and then use .ClientID

Comment: @bugnuker in fact it is inside of a repeater wich is inside a repeater wich is inside a WebUserControl wich is inside a contentPlaceHolder.

Comment: try something like contendido.FindControl(rtpMateriales).FindControl(rptFilasDeUnMaterial).FindControl(txtValorMaterialAsign).ClientID

Comment: @HanletEscaño I could do it like `((TextBox)((TextBox)sender).Parent.FindControl("txtValorMaterialAsign")).ClientID` but it result in the same short ClientId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
var myResult1 = FindControl("ctl00").FindControl("MainContent")
                                    .FindControl("text1").UniqueID;
```

returns:

> ctl00$MainContent$text1

Try `UniqueID` on your simple findControl. If that does not work, nest the findControls.

Comment: UniqueId returns the same thing but with $ instead of _.

Comment: $ is the "name" and _ is in the "id" of the control.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with this ID, but I do know jQuery can find this control with a wildcard. If you give it your value of "txtValorMaterialAsign", jquery (client side) will find it just fine. Don't know if this helps or not.

Comment: here is a sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388575/how-to-get-nested-controls-clientid-using-javascript

Comment: Finally I changed the way I was doing that in order to avoid this problem, so I didn't try your suggestion. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this gives you an idea:

HTML:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
  <asp:Repeater ID="repPeople" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" OnDataBinding="text_databinding" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Content>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Person> tmp = new List<Person>();
        tmp.Add(new Person() { LastName = "Escano", Name = "Hanlet" });
        tmp.Add(new Person() { LastName = "Escano", Name = "Hanlet" });
        tmp.Add(new Person() { LastName = "Escano", Name = "Hanlet" });
        tmp.Add(new Person() { LastName = "Escano", Name = "Hanlet" });
        tmp.Add(new Person() { LastName = "Escano", Name = "Hanlet" });
        this.repPeople.DataSource = tmp;
        this.repPeople.DataBind();
    }
    public void text_databinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        Response.Write(((TextBox)sender).ClientID + "<br />") ;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
MainContent_repPeople_txtName_0
MainContent_repPeople_txtName_1
MainContent_repPeople_txtName_2
MainContent_repPeople_txtName_3
MainContent_repPeople_txtName_4
```

So pretty much use the OnDataBinding of your textboxes, and then cast the sender to `TextBox`, you won't even need to use `FindControl()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is exactly how I'm doing it, but ClientID doesn't give me the full Id that the browser resolves.

Comment: That is very bizarre. What is this Repeater's parent?

Comment: Yes it is strange, I use ClientID+Repeaters all the time without any problem. The nesting is like this: the TextBox inside of a repeater wich is inside another repeater wich is inside a WebUserControl wich is inside a contentPlaceHolder.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this ..

To find a control in the **header**:

```
textcontrol = repeater1.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("txtValorMaterialAsign");
```

To find a control in the **footer**:

```
textcontrol = repeater1.Controls[repeater1.Controls.Count - 1].Controls[0].FindControl("txtValorMaterialAsign");
```

---

### With extension methods

```
public static class RepeaterExtensionMethods
{
    public static Control FindControlInHeader(this Repeater repeater, string controlName)
    {
        return repeater.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl(controlName);
    }

    public static Control FindControlInFooter(this Repeater repeater, string controlName)
    {
        return repeater.Controls[repeater.Controls.Count - 1].Controls[0].FindControl(controlName);
    }
}
```

Comment: It says "The name 'txtValorMaterialAsign' does not exist in the current context" since txtValorMaterialAsign is inside a Repeater. I tried with Request.Form[((TextBox)sender).UniqueID] but it result in null.

Comment: you will need to do FindControl then and your casting in that example would not work in your case..